# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider

Tags: java

I am trying to upgrade to Akka 2.3.2 using java 1.6. So i got this kind of exception. I have tried to add the scala-library jar file and the typesafe conf jar file but I still get this exception.. can anyone please advise me on how to fix this problem.Thanx

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider.<init>(java.lang.String, akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings, akka.event.EventStream, akka.actor.DynamicAccess)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2715)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1987)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:76)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree1$1(ActorSystem.scala:584)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:66)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
    at com.indaba.processor.singletons.ClusterActorSystemSingleton.createActorSystem(ClusterActorSystemSingleton.java:65)
    at com.indaba.processor.singletons.ClusterActorSystemSingleton.getActorSystem(ClusterActorSystemSingleton.java:42)
    at com.indaba.processor.frontend.eventProcessingService.SubmitEvent(eventProcessingService.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Thank you.Its now working, it was reading the old akka in the CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you compiled your code with new Akka version but old Akka version still exists on CLASSPATH and JVM picks it for execution.

Comment: I see, I reading the configs from application.conf which looks like this:akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2551
      message-frame-size = 3 MiB
    }
  }
 
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551", 
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]
 
    auto-down = on
  }
}